# Why is `$@` untrustworthy?

Tags: perl, exception, eval, race-condition

I seem to recall that it is not safe to trust the value of `$@` after an `eval`.  Something about a signal handler having a chance to set `$@` before you see it or something.  I am also too tired and lazy right now to track down the real reason.  So, why is it not safe to trust `$@`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/is-object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-worth-it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not

Comment: Note that as Perl 5.14, [This has been fixed.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Exception-Handling)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny#Clobbering_$@) perldoc has the definitive discussion of the trouble with `$@`:

> There are a number of issues with eval.
>
> **Clobbering $@**
>
> When you run an eval block and it succeeds, $@ will be cleared, potentially clobbering an error that is currently being caught.
>
> This causes action at a distance, clearing previous errors your caller may have not yet handled.
>
> $@ must be properly localized before invoking eval in order to avoid this issue.
>
> More specifically, $@ is clobbered at the beginning of the eval, which also makes it impossible to capture the previous error before you die (for instance when making exception objects with error stacks).
>
> For this reason try will actually set $@ to its previous value (before the localization) in the beginning of the eval block.
>
> **Localizing $@ silently masks errors**
>
> Inside an eval block die behaves sort of like:
>
> ```
> sub die {
>         $@ = $_[0];
>         return_undef_from_eval();
> }
> ```
>
> This means that if you were polite and localized $@ you can't die in that scope, or your error will be discarded (printing "Something's wrong" instead).
>
> The workaround is very ugly:
>
> ```
> my $error = do {
>         local $@;
>         eval { ... };
>         $@;
> };
>
> ...
> die $error;
> ```
>
> **$@ might not be a true value**
>
> This code is wrong:
>
> ```
> if ( $@ ) {
>         ...
> }
> ```
>
> because due to the previous caveats it may have been unset.
>
> $@ could also be an overloaded error object that evaluates to false, but that's asking for trouble anyway.
>
> The classic failure mode is:
>
> ```
> sub Object::DESTROY {
>         eval { ... }
> }
>
> eval {
>         my $obj = Object->new;
>
>         die "foo";
> };
>
> if ( $@ ) {
>
> }
> ```
>
> In this case since Object::DESTROY is not localizing $@ but still uses eval, it will set $@ to "".
>
> The destructor is called when the stack is unwound, after die sets $@ to "foo at Foo.pm line 42\n", so by the time if ( $@ ) is evaluated it has been cleared by eval in the destructor.
>
> The workaround for this is even uglier than the previous ones. Even though we can't save the value of $@ from code that doesn't localize, we can at least be sure the eval was aborted due to an error:
>
> ```
> my $failed = not eval {
>         ...
>
>         return 1;
> };
> ```
>
> This is because an eval that caught a die will always return a false value.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is what I was remembering.

Comment: Don't have to play those insane games anymore.

Answer (score 13):

The [Try::Tiny docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND) have a pretty good list of `eval`/`$@` shortcomings. I think you might be refering to the [Localizing $@ silently masks errors](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#Localizing_%24@_silently_masks_errors) section in there.

Answer (score 7):

`$@` has the same problems that every global variable has: when something else sets it, it's reset across the entire program. Any `eval` might set `$@`. Even if you don't see an `eval` nearby, you don't know who else might call one (subroutines, tied variables, and so on).