# What are the common pitfalls when using Perl's eval?

Tags: perl, exception, eval

What are the common pitfalls associated with Perl's [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), which might make you choose to use a module such as [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try%3a%3aTiny)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is `$@` untrustworthy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686857/why-is-untrustworthy), [What's broken about exceptions in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/)

Comment: The only reason you would not use the builtin is you aren't running a current version of Perl.

Comment: @mob - yes, that appears to be the same question.

Comment: @tchrist - I'm not really sure what you mean by "current". From what I've now read, I can't see that the pitfalls of eval have been resolved in more recent versions of Perl.

Comment: Run 5.14 or better and tell me whether that works for you.

Comment: @tchrist Indeed it is. Thanks for pointing it out. I can't believe I missed that. Here is the link for reference: http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.14.2/pod/perl5140delta.pod#Exception_Handling

Comment: @tchrist, are you saying that Try::Tiny is completely obsolete (aside from syntactic sugar/aesthetic preferences) as of 5.14? Or do you still see it having a place in 5.14+ code?

Comment: @Dave: I **very much hope** it is obsolete, but I haven’t exhaustively investigated the matter either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Perl's `eval` comes in two flavors, string eval and block eval.  String eval invokes the compiler to execute source code.  Block eval surrounds already compiled code in a wrapper that will catch the `die` exception.  (string eval catches the `die` exception also, as well as any compilation errors).

Try::Tiny only applies to the block form of eval, but the following applies to both forms.

Every time you call `eval` it will change the value of `$@`.  It will either be `''` if the eval succeeded or the error caught by the eval.

This means that any time you call an eval, you will clear any previous error messages.  `Try::Tiny` localizes the `$@` variable for you, so that a successful eval will not clear the message of a previous failed eval.

The other pitfall comes from using `$@` as the check to determine if the eval succeeded.  A common pattern is:

```
eval {...};
if ($@) {
   # deal with error here
}
```

This relies on two assumptions, first that any error message `$@` could contain is a true value (usually true), and that there is no code between the eval block and the if statement.

Visually of course the latter is true, but if the eval block created an object, and that object went out of scope after the eval failed, then the object's `DESTROY` method will be called before the `if` statement.  If `DESTROY` happens to call eval without localizing `$@` and it succeeds, then by the time your `if` statement is run, the `$@` variable will be cleared.

The solution to these problems is:

```
my $return = do {
    local $@;
    my $ret;
    eval {$ret = this_could_fail(); 1} or die "eval failed: $@";
    $ret
};
```

breaking that apart line by line, the `local $@` creates a new `$@` for the `do` block which prevents clobbering previous values.  `my $ret` will be the return value of the evaluated code.  In the eval block, `$ret` is assigned to, and then the block returns `1`.  That way, no matter what, if the eval succeeds it will return true, and if it fails it will return false.  It is up to you what to do in the case of failure.  The code above just dies, but you could easily use the return value of the eval block to decide to run other code.

Since the above incantation is a bit tedious, it becomes error prone.  Using a module like `Try::Tiny` insulates you from those potential errors, at the cost of a few more function calls per eval.  It is important to know how to use eval properly, because `Try::Tiny` is not going to help you if you have to use a string eval.

Comment: Fixed in the current release.

Comment: Tiny correction - `$@` will actually be an empty string rather than undef if no exception was thrown.

Comment: @Grant McLean => thanks, I should have remembered, because that's how my usual repl deals with errors: `perl -wE 'say eval, $@ while <>'`

Answer (score 11):

The issues are explained in the [Try::Tiny documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#BACKGROUND). Briefly, they are:

- [Clobbering `$@`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#Clobbering_$@)
- [Localizing `$@` silently masks errors](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#Localizing_$@_silently_masks_errors)
- [`$@` might not be a true value](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny#$@_might_not_be_a_true_value)

Comment: Thanks. Although I read the introduction on Try:Tiny, I failed to read the Background section.

Comment: Fixed in the current release.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers above, I would add...

- eval is affected by the global `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler causing action at a distance.
- It is easy for a novice to confuse `eval BLOCK` and `eval STRING`, since they appear to do the same thing, but one is a security hole.

Try::Tiny has its own pitfalls, the biggest being that while it looks like a block it is actually a subroutine call.  That means this:

```
eval {
    ...blah blah...
    return $foo;
};
```

and this:

```
try {
    ...blah blah...
    return $foo;
};
```

do not do the same thing.  These are laid out in the [CAVEATS section of the Try::Tiny docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny#CAVEATS).  That said, I'd recommend it over `eval`.

Comment: Are you saying that `eval` is *still* unusably broken in 5.14?  **Really?** That would be *extremely* disappointing, because I know a lot of work went into it to try to render `Try::Tiny` obsolete by fixing whatever underlying bugs plagued `eval`. If that effort failed, then there is a horrible problem because `Try::Tiny` is still merely a CPAN module, not core. If you cannot do real work, and reliably, with the core, then that is an unacceptable situation.

Comment: @tchrist Forgot about that.  As I understand it, 5.14.0 fixed a class of bugs having to do with interactions between $@ and object destruction and generally made `eval { ... }; if( $@ ) { ... }` more reliable. I believe that solves 2 of the 3 things Try::Tiny fixes... and the third (a false $@) is pretty unlikely. It still leaves the points I mentioned. It would be a nice 5.16 feature to stop `$SIG{__DIE__}` from firing inside an eval. And dial down the drama, dude.

Comment: Calling `eval STRING` a “security problem” is not just overly dramatic; it isn’t even true. I’ve used `eval STRING` since it first appeared in perl2 some twenty-three years ago, I can assure you that never once have I experienced any so-called “security problem” with it. Sure, dumb programmers can do dumb things with it, but this is true of nearly anything. If you exist in a pathologically paranoid world, you should be using taint mode and/or Safe compartments. In a normal world, `eval STRING` gets a lot of useful work done; see the classic *rename* program.

Comment: @tchrist Not all security problems are code bugs, a lot are programmer mistakes encouraged by bad interfaces.  eval runs two very different pieces of functionality, yet with apparently the same effect, through the same function.  It is very, very easy to use `eval STRING` where `eval BLOCK` would do, creating a security hole.  For example, the ubiquitous `eval "require $module"`. http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=eval%5C%20%5C%22require%5C%20%5C$%20lang:%5Eperl$&type=cs

Comment: He who  passes tainted data to `eval STRING` gets what he deserves.  If `$module` is untrusted user input, then you are going to be letting that user specify code to run no matter what you do. Don’t do that. And anyway, you cannot just go replacing the string version you cite with an `eval BLOCK`. You are forgetting how `require` works. It is simply not always possible.

Comment: @tchrist He who designs an interface where the easy, obvious paths are blocked or full of traps deserves a far worse fate.

Answer (score 0):

Using eval on X11 function might still failed to keep alive.

The code is like

```
eval {    
    @win_arrays = GetWindowsFromPid($pid);
};
```

The script will be exited from

> X Error of failed request:  ...