# How can I prevent my perl script from terminating if an exception is thrown in a module it uses?

Tags: perl, exception, die

I have a perl script, using standard-as-dirt Net::HTTP code, and perl 5.8.8.
I have come across an error condition in which the server returns 0 bytes of data when I call:

```
$_http_connection->read_response_headers;
```

Unfortunately, my perl script `die`s, because the Net::HTTP::Methods module has a "die" on line 306:

```
Server closed connection without sending any data back at
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 306
```

And lines 305-307 are, of course:

```
unless (defined $status) {
die "Server closed connection without sending any data back";
}
```

How can I have my script "recover gracefully" from this situation, detecting the `die` and subsequently going into my own error-handling code, instead of `die`ing itself?

I'm sure this is a common case, and probably something simple, but I have not come across it before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `eval { }` to catch `die()` exceptions. Use `$@` to inspect the thrown value:

```
eval {
    die "foo";
};
print "the block died with $@" if $@;
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html for details.

Comment: Before Perl 5.14 the `eval` is better written as `my $success = eval { code_that_may_die(); 1; }; if (!$success) { print "Error: $@" }` This is due to a fairly rare issue that the value of `$@` might get cleared as the `eval` block is exited. From 5.14 on either way will work.

Answer (score 12):

Using [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to catch exceptions [can occasionally be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598425/what-are-the-common-pitfalls-when-using-perls-eval), especially pre 5.14. You can use [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny).

Comment: I can't install modules on this system, and it's a rare issue I'm trying to catch, so "eval" will have to do for now, but I'll keep Try::Tiny in mind for other projects. Thanks.

Comment: If you can put a script on that system, you can use `Try::Tiny` on that system as well, even if you just copy &amp; paste the module source code in your script.

Comment: Technically sure, but it isn't worth the effort, for the amount of problems this is going to solve with this little internal script. Even when it dies due to Net::HTTP problem, it's just a matter of whether we log the problem before dieing ourselves or not. If we miss it, it is not the end of the world. :)

Answer (score 2):

Customizing the `die` to mean something else is simple:

```
sub custom_exception_handler { ... } # Define custom logic

local $SIG{__DIE__} = \&custom_exception_handler;  # Won't die now
# Calls custom_exception_handler instead
```

The big advantage of this approach over  `eval` is that it doesn't require calling another perl interpreter to execute the problematic code.

Of course, the custom exception handler should be adequate for the task at hand.